# Using Process to Create a DMG with hdiutil

Tags: swift, macos, hdiutil

I'm having a play with `Process()` and trying to get it to create a DMG on my Desktop.

**The code I'm trying is:**

```
func terminal(_ args:String...) -> integer_t{
print(args)
let task = Process()
let dataPipe = Pipe()
let errPipe = Pipe()


task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/hdiutil"
task.arguments = args
task.standardOutput = dataPipe
task.standardError = errPipe

task.launch()

task.waitUntilExit()

let data = dataPipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
let output = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

let dataErr = errPipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
let errOp = String(data: dataErr, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
print (errOp)


return task.terminationStatus}
```

`terminal("create", "size 50m" ,"fs HFS+" , "volname test", "Users/me/Desktop")`

**But currently it throws an error**

`hdiutil: create: Only one image can be created at a time.\nUsage:\thdiutil create <sizespec> [options] <imagepath>\n\thdiutil create -help\n`

I guess I have something wrong with the way the arguments are parsed but not sure what.

Thanks for any help!

UPDATE:

I think maybe its seeing the arguments as seperate calls? The top of the returned error reads

`["create", "size 50m", "fs HFS+", "/Users/me/Desktop/test.dmg"]
hdiutil: create: Only one image can be created at a time.`

I put the `-` back into the arguments but now it says
`hdiutil: create: unknown option "-size 50M"`. Definitely something to do with how the arguments are formatted but seems correct I think??

Comment: I think that last argument should be something like `/Users/me/Desktop/testimage.dmg`, no?

Comment: Hmm. Just tried that and same message

Comment: You're passing the options wrong. There should be a dash on `size`, `fs`, and `volname`, and the parameter to those need to be separate arguments, not part of the same argument. Also, "Users/me/Desktop" is a relative path (doesn't start with "/"), but looks like it should be absolute. Try: `terminal("create", "-size", "50m" ,"-fs", "HFS+" , "-volname", "test", "/Users/me/Desktop")`

Comment: @GordonDavisson. Thanks. I just got there myself. I omitted the `-` at first thinking that was the issue but as you rightly point out I had to split out the parameter values. Cheers.